# How to pass a path as an argument to Process.Start

Tags: c#, path, escaping, backslash, xcopy

the following code speaks for itself. When I try to xcopy a local folder to a networkshare, the paths get all messed up and CMD can't interpet correctly the backslashes. Any suggestions are welcome, already tried everything I found on the web (been stuck almost for 2 hours on this):

```
string command = "xcopy /s " + @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TempExtract\MyApp\*.* " + @"\\TestShare\SharedFolder\Applications\ /Y /I";
Process Processo = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo Xcopy = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
Xcopy.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Xcopy.Arguments = command;
Processo = Process.Start(Xcopy);
Processo.WaitForExit();
```

The problem here is that "Arguments" can't decode "\\" to "\" so my paths are like:

```
C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TempExtract\\MyApp\\*.*
```

And CMD can't interpert double backslashes :( help!

Comment: Try changing command to `string command = "/C xcopy /s " + @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TempExtract\MyApp\*.* " + @"\\TestShare\SharedFolder\Applications\ /Y /I";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the way you setup `ProcessStartInfo`. So `command` should be:

```
string command = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TempExtract\MyApp\*.* " + @"\\TestShare\SharedFolder\Applications\ /Y /I";
```

and add

```
Xcopy.FileName = "xcopy";
```

this is what worked for me:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var command = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TempExtract\MyApp\*.* " + @"\\TestShare\SharedFolder\Applications\ /Y /I";
        var Processo = new Process();
        var Xcopy = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            Arguments = command,
            FileName = "xcopy",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        Processo = Process.Start(Xcopy);
        Processo.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my day :) thank you very much, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

try adding `/c` in the beginning or the command string (as the cmd.exe launches the following command through the /c parameter, check the help of cmd.exe).
If that doesn't do the trick, add `\"` around your paths.